# PHP PDO confusion

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following doesn't seem to set the $_SERVER variable in windows.

```
//Parse the properties
parse_ini_file("../../props/config.ini");

        //      Create a new PDO instanace
        try {
                $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $_SERVER['DB_USER'], $_SERVER['DB_PASS'], $options);
                // Connection succeeded, set the boolean to true.
                $this->dbcon = true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Please could someone help me figure this out. I'd highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Check this path `parse_ini_file("../../props/config.ini");` for windows

Comment: check `pdo` extension is enabled or not...

Comment: Hello Saty - He path looks right. He file is being parsed ( Verified this by changing to an incorrect path)

Comment: Hello Nishant - I;ll verify this. Good lead. Thank you. 'm currently on wamp developer pro on windows. Unsure of hte supported packages

Comment: To debug this I would put: `var_dump($dsn, $_SERVER['DB_USER'], $_SERVER['DB_PASS'], __FILE__.__LINE__);` immediately before the `new PDO` line. The `ini` file looks odd for windows - it isn't a valid `ini` file for windows? I would expect to see `putenv` commands in an ordinary PHP file, which are the PHP versions for adding stuff to `$_SERVER`. I thought the apache  `SetEnv` would be in `.htaccess`? I use XAMPP on windows. I do know that the PHP windows stuff works on linux as that is how I deploy stuff.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. Looks like the problem is just what you suspected it to be. This is the output of the debug statement  string(19) "mysql:host=;dbname=" NULL NULL string(69) "C:\WampDeveloper\Websites\proj1\webroot\class\dbmanage.class.php37"

Comment: Could you please show me how to set those variables so that I can still continue to access via $_SERVER variable?

Comment: example taken from my `application bootstrap` file: `putenv('RTV_APP_ENVIRONMENT=dev');` will do what you expect when you look in `$_SERVER`. `getenv('RTV_APP_ENVIRONMENT');` to access the value. `getenv` checks `$_ENV` as well as `$_SERVER`This works in all version of PHP on all platforms.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. HIghly appreciate your help. I followed the blog at https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advice from this thread, I managed to get this working. Thank you very much to all.

Here is what I did to get this working -

Changed `parse_ini_file("..\..\props\config.ini");` to

```
  $props =  parse_ini_file("..\..\props\config.ini");
```

Replaced `$_SERVER` with `$props` in `$this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $props['DB_USER'], $props['DB_PASS'], $options);`

Comment: Your "config.ini" was actually part of your Apache configuration, which is why you were able to access the variables with `$_SERVER` before.

Comment: Absolutely Mike. Thanks for this.